# How I can impute mean to a specific column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I am trying to compute mean to a specific column in my data frame. The names of the columns are in a list.

```
for col in ValIndex: #ValIndex has the columns name
    dataSet[col] = dataSet[col].fillna(dataSet[col].mean())
```

I get this error when I run my code:

`can only concatenate str (not "int") to str`

Comment: Hi! Does one of your variables contains strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error, it is evident that the columns you are trying to impute are of type object (str). You would need to first convert / cast them into numeric to enable calculation of a mean of that column (Series).

There are two ways to convert the columns to float (OR int type) depending on the values in the columns:

1) If your columns definitely contain all numerics, you can convert them to float type as below:

```
data[col] = data[col].astype(float)
dataSet[col] = dataSet[col].fillna(dataSet[col].mean())
```

OR

2) If your column values can be numeric and non-numeric both, then convert them to numeric as below:

```
data[col] = pd.to_numeric(data[col],errors='coerce')
dataSet[col] = dataSet[col].fillna(dataSet[col].mean())
```

Once converted, you should be able to calculate mean and impute the Series.